# Extract info from adf file into json

Tags: geojson, esri-grid-format, mongodb

I have a .adf file which contains altitude data.

Is it possible to read and convert this file in JSON format for a next loading on mongoDB?

My directory structure is:

```
SRTM_1km_GRD

| --- info

      | --- arc.dir

      | --- arc0273.dat

      | --- arc0273.nit

      | --- arc0274.dat

      | --- arc0274.nit

      | --- arc0275.dat

      | --- arc0275.nit

      | --- arc0275r.001

      | --- arc0273.dat


| --- srtmv4_30s

      | --- dblbnd.adf

      | --- hdr.adf

      | --- log

      | --- metadata.xml

      | --- prj.adf

      | --- sta.adf

      | --- vat.adf

      | --- w001001.adf

      | --- w001001x.adf
```

Can I read this data with ArcGis ?

Comment: Please edit your question and specify which ArcGIS product and version. 
Basic steps are convert raster to points, convert points to geojson.